# Silverlight, C#: Detect when there are no more images

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a list of consecutive images that need to be loaded in order when the user clicks "next".  The next page is determined by adding one to the number at the end of a url like so: `http://twoimages.com/image_1` to `http://twoimages.com/image_2`.  I want to be able to detect when there are no more images to load.  I could use an event but that fires only after it has failed and finished running the rest of my code.

```
public void LoadImage(string ImageUrl)
{
    BitmapImage bmpImage;
    if (this.SilverlightImage.Source is BitmapImage)
    {
        bmpImage = this.SilverlightImage.Source as BitmapImage;
    }
    else
    {
        bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
        bmpImage.DownloadProgress += new EventHandler<DownloadProgressEventArgs>(bitmapImage_DownloadProgress);
    }

    bmpImage.UriSource = new Uri(ImageUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    if (this.SilverlightImage.Source == null)
    {
        this.SilverlightImage.Source = bmpImage;    
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to detect when there are no more images to load and do not even try to load an image that doesn't exist.

Thank you,

Aaron

Comment: Did you find any new solution? I am facing a similar proplem which causes me headaches for days...

Answer (score 0):

You can request a full list of images or the count of them at the beginning, than start to load... I don't think you can send information about next image withe BitmapSource, may be image reserved bytes can help, but that will be just Hack

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't have a known number of images or some other data known to the program at runtime to see if the image URI is valid, the way to handle this would be to make a call to the file system on the server to see if the image exists before trying to load it (perhaps by creating a service that returns whether a given file exists), which seems far less efficient than simply trying to load the image.  Because that service call would need to be asynchronous (as all service calls are in Silverlight), you'd be looking at restructuring your code to listen to events anyway, though you could make this a pretty closed loop.

The bigger question I think is why: if you're trying to reduce the overhead of running the rest of your code, this would only be counterproductive as multiple network calls are almost certain to take more overhead/time than any code you'd be running.

The only other method that comes to mind would be to write a service that returns some kind of complex object containing both your image and a flag to tell you if the next image is available.  That seems to be overkill, but it might be worth looking into if you really need to know if the next image is there before you try to load it.  Again, I'd point out that this service would need to be called asynchronously, so you're listening for events in any case, and the service you'll be creating isn't exactly trivial (you'd need some kid of WCF service that would return a complex object).  I would also consider this solution not to be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The most sensible approach to this problem is to download a "Manifest of images" first.  This could be a simple XML file or simple ashx that generates the xml.  There is no real need to do anything heavier like building a service or using WCF.

You then use the list of urls in this XML to pass to your LoadImage method and you can disable the Next button when you get to the last one (and disable the Prev button when you are at the first one).

Not only is this light weight but it would allow use of meaningful filenames and perhaps addition of other meta-data you might want to include with images in future.

**If you really must**

However if you really do need a quick way to check the existance of a file you can use a `ClientHTTP` instance to `HttpWebRequest` to make a "HEAD" request for the file.  However this may be more difficult if you are using cookie based security.